# convert firestore timestamp to date into different format

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

the timestamp variable is stored in the firestore , and when extracted it is then in the format of seconds and nanoseconds , how to convert the timestamp to the format like 2018-09-19T00:00:00

```
let Ref=firebase.firestore().collection("Recruiter").doc(u.uid).collection("Jobs")
    Ref.orderBy("timestamp", "desc").onSnapshot(function(snapshot){
      $.each(snapshot.docChanges(), function(){
        var change= this
        if(change.type==="added"){
           var ab= new Date(change.doc.data().timestamp) 
           console.log(ab)
          thisIns.RecruiterChart.chartOptions.xaxis.categories.push(
            ab
            ) 

           console.log( thisIns.RecruiterChart.chartOptions.xaxis.categories)
        }

      })
    })
```

the variable ab is showing "invalid date" on the console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#todate) method of the Firestore [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp):

> Convert a Timestamp to a JavaScript Date object. This conversion
>   causes a loss of precision since Date objects only support millisecond
>   precision.
>
> Returns `Date`
>
> JavaScript Date object representing the same point in time as this
>   Timestamp, with millisecond precision.

So, you would do the following:

```
var timestampDate = change.doc.data().timestamp.toDate(); 
console.log(timestampDate);
```

Then, you need to format this date as desired. The easiest is to use a dedicated library like [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/), as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

// ...

<script>

   // ...

    var timestampDate = change.doc.data().timestamp.toDate(); 
    var m = moment(timestampDate );
    var mFormatted = m.format();    // "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" (ISO 8601, no fractional seconds) 
    console.log(mFormatted );

    // ...

</script>
```

Other possibilities for formatting a date with `moment.js` are to be found [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Answer (score 1):

I think I know whats happening.

Your `ab` variable should be in string format, right?

Try parsing it to Number first.. and see what happens.

Try logging something like:

```
var ab= new Date(Number(change.doc.data().timestamp))
console.log(ab)
thisIns.RecruiterChart.chartOptions.xaxis.categories.push(
  ab
) 

console.log( thisIns.RecruiterChart.chartOptions.xaxis.categories)
```

OR

```
var ab= new Date(parseInt(change.doc.data().timestamp, 10))
console.log(ab)
thisIns.RecruiterChart.chartOptions.xaxis.categories.push(
  ab
) 
console.log( thisIns.RecruiterChart.chartOptions.xaxis.categories)
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

`var ab = change.doc.data().timestamp.toDate().toLocaleDateString('en-US')`
// 7/2/2021

or more:

`var ab = change.doc.data().timestamp.toDate().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday:"long", year:"numeric", month:"short", day:"numeric"})` 
// Friday, Jul 2, 2021

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString